# Android change Default "Paste" popup text color of edittext

Tags: android, popup, android-theme, android-color

I have an edittext field and when I want to paste someone on it, the text color of the "Paste" popup (**Th System default "Paste" popup**, NOT by custom) isn't the same as the app global text color and still remains black and very difficult to read with:

[image: Paste Popup]

Here is my overall theme styles:

style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!---->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_main_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/general_text_textsize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_background_color</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/GeneralEditTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="AppActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_background_color</item>
</style>

<style name="GeneralEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/general_all_rect_border_transparent_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_main_text_color</item>
</style>
```

color.xml

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#16365C</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>

<color name="app_background_color">#16365C</color>

<color name="app_main_text_color">#FFFFFF</color>
```

I tired to change the parent theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and nothing in the "paste" dialog is changed at all.

So, how to change the text color of this "Paste" popup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And apply this theme to your popUp. It helped me for the overflow menu in the toolbar.

Comment: <item name="popupTheme">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay</item> Tried to add this on AppTheme in style.xml but it's not working. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Not in apptheme. Add this style in your style.xml file. And when you opening the popUp of the paste give it style as the popupTheme

Comment: @passer are you using custom popup for **"PASTE"** or default?

Comment: It is the default "PASTE" popup by the system

Comment: Tried to add the style in style.xml and not working. Is this solution only working on custom popup?

Comment: That worked for me for the case of overflow menu in the toolbar.